# Send multipart/mixed response using Koa

Tags: koa2

We need to send a multipart/mixed response (with a JSON part followed by one or more binary parts) using Koa. Note this is a **response**, not a request.

Does anyone know of any "out of the box" support for this, or do we need to roll our own?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is nice and easy. We can use https://github.com/hendrikcech/multipart-stream to construct a multipart stream and then just set that as `ctx.body`.

For example, in the route handler:

```
const multipart = new Multipart();

multipart.addPart({
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Content-Disposition": `form-data; name="json"`
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(myJSONContent)
});

multipart.addPart({
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
    "Content-Disposition": `form-data; name="binary-data"`
  },
  body: myBinaryBuffer
});

ctx.body = multipart;
ctx.response.type = "multipart/mixed";
```